# Is it ok to use Kubernetes autoscaling v2beta2 in production as apiVersion?

Tags: kubernetes, autoscaling, hpa

I have use case to scale pods (HPA) based on memory (and custom metrics).

However respective apiVersion is in beta (autoscaling/v2beta2).

Not sure when this will be in GA/stable version, hence checking.

Any advise for me?

Answer (score 5):

If you look at the [Kubernetes API Versioning doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/kubernetes-api/#api-versioning) and the [API deprecation policy doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/deprecation-policy/) there is no clear indication as to when `autoscaling/v2` will be available (GA).

For example, in the next Kubernetes release, the API could be either `autoscaling/v2beta2` or `autoscaling/v2` depending on how the release/feature team feels about it in terms of satisfying 'Stability'

Having said that based on the deprecation policy and [rule 4a here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/deprecation-policy/#deprecating-parts-of-the-api), you should be safe to use `autoscaling/v2beta2` (for at least the next 3 Kubernetes releases after `autoscaling/v2` or `autoscaling/v2beta3` is announced.

So let's hypothetically say `autoscaling/v2` is released with K8s 1.19, then `autoscaling/v2beta2` would be available in Kubernetes 1.20, 1.21 and 1.22.